# Ionic 3 navcontroller pop twice with modal got not consistent history

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a Ionic 3 project with multiples pages.
There is the step of navigation :

- Home
- Item List
- Item
- Modal of item

In the modal, there is a button of confirmation. I want this button return to ItemList. After returned on Item List, the back button should return user to Home.

But, I have the same error of this one ([Ionic 2 Angular NavController, pop back to second last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361740/ionic-2-angular-navcontroller-pop-back-to-second-last-page))

I tried the solution proposed by high vote answer but it fails.

## Project code

### Home

#### home.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button type="submit" (click)="goToList()">Go to list</button>
</ion-content>
```

#### home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ItemlistPage } from '../itemlist/itemlist';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}

  goToList() {
    this.navCtrl.push(ItemlistPage);
  }

}
```

### ItemList

#### itemlist.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>itemlist</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item (click)="goToItem()">Item 1</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="goToItem()">Item 2</button>  
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

#### itemlist.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ItemPage } from '../item/item';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-itemlist',
  templateUrl: 'itemlist.html',
})
export class ItemlistPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {}

  goToItem() {
    this.navCtrl.push(ItemPage);
  }

}
```

### Item

#### item.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>item</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button type="submit" (click)="openModal()">Open modal</button>
</ion-content>
```

#### item.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ItemmodalPage } from '../itemmodal/itemmodal';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-item',
  templateUrl: 'item.html',
})
export class ItemPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public modalController: ModalController) {
  }

  openModal() {
    let myModal = this.modalController.create(ItemmodalPage);
    myModal.present();
  }

}
```

#### ItemModal

### itemmodal.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>itemmodal</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-item (click)="returnToList()">Return to list</button>
</ion-content>
```

### itemmodal.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ItemlistPage } from '../itemlist/itemlist';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-itemmodal',
  templateUrl: 'itemmodal.html',
})
export class ItemmodalPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  returnToList() {
    this.navCtrl.push(ItemlistPage).then(() => {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.navCtrl.length(); i++) {
        console.log('Stack history Before: '+i);
        console.log(this.navCtrl.getByIndex(i).component);
      }

      this.navCtrl.remove(1, 3);
      this.navCtrl.pop();

      // Debug lines
      for (var i = 0; i < this.navCtrl.length(); i++) {
        console.log('Stack history After : '+i);
        console.log(this.navCtrl.getByIndex(i).component);
      }
      });
  }

}
```

## Result of code

When I click in the modal button, I excepected debug console.log() line displays :

```
Stack history Before: 0
function ItemListPage()

Stack history Before: 1
function ModalCmp()

Stack history Before: 2
function ItemPage()

Stack history Before: 3
function ItemListPage()

Stack history Before: 4
function HomePage()


Stack history Before: 0
function ItemListPage()

Stack history Before: 1
function HomePage()
```

But I got this :

```
Stack history Before: 0
function ModalCmp()

Stack history Before: 1
function ItemlistPage()

Stack history After : 0
function ModalCmp()

Stack history After : 1
function ItemlistPage()
```

I don't understand why I got only history with ModalCmp and ItemListPage and not HomePage and ItemPage.

Do you know a way to cleanly return to ItemList ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

Indeed, modal Component has his own history, so it's impossible to modify the main history of the modal component. We should **dismiss** the modal to return in the precedent view and access to main history to do a **navCtrl.pop()**.

## Conclusion

Finally, Ionic Modals can't access to main views histories.

## Files changed

### itemmodals.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ItemlistPage } from '../itemlist/itemlist';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-itemmodal',
  templateUrl: 'itemmodal.html',
})
export class ItemmodalPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
  }

  returnToList() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss({'action' :'remove'});
  }

}
```

### item.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ItemmodalPage } from '../itemmodal/itemmodal';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-item',
  templateUrl: 'item.html',
})
export class ItemPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public modalController: ModalController) {
  }

  openModal() {
    let myModal = this.modalController.create(ItemmodalPage);
    myModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
      if (data.action == 'remove') {
        this.navCtrl.pop();
      }
   });
    myModal.present();
  }

}
```